# Is it possible to read incoming emails on PowerMTA?

Tags: php, email, http, nginx, smtp

It may be a stupid question but I send emails today with PowerMTA and I would like to configure a feedback loop on Yahoo :

**What I tried so far :**

- my PowerMTA conf file is OKAY to send emails and to track bounces
- I added in the conf file a feedback-loop-processor like this one:

  ```
  <feedback-loop-processor>
      deliver-email no
      forward-unmatched-to feedback@mydomain.com
      forward-errors-to feedback@mydomain.com

      <address-list>
          address /postmaster@mydomain.com/
      </address-list>
  </feedback-loop-processor>`
  ```

where postmaster@mydomain.com is a required email address for Yahoo.

**Question :**
Is it possible to read incoming emails in PMTA (eg: emails sent to postmaster@mydomain.com), or do I need to install a POP3 email server (such as Dovecot) ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why do you want to read them?

Setting up the FBL Log processor will output the ARF data, when set informatively will give you all of the information needed to digest the abuse report.

```
#FBL Log
```

`{acct-file /var/log/xyz.csv}
   delete-after                    2d
   max-size                        5M
   sync                            no

   records                            f
   record-fields                      f *,variables,etc
 {/acct-file}`